# How to produce localized date string with CultureInfo

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, cultureinfo

I have the following code that produces a date string in en-us format. I would like to pass in the LCID (or equivalent value for the localized language) to produce the localized version of the date string. How would I accomplish this?

```
public static string ConvertDateTimeToDate(string dateTimeString) {

    CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
    DateTime dt = DateTime.MinValue;

    if (DateTime.TryParse(dateTimeString, out dt))
    {
        return dt.ToShortDateString();
    }
    return dateTimeString;
  }
```

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You can use the second argument to the [toString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8tfzyc64.aspx#Y1100) function and use any language/culture you need...

You can use the "d" format instead of `ToShortDateString` according to MSDN...

So basically something like this to return as Australian English:

```
CultureInfo enAU = new CultureInfo("en-AU");
dt.ToString("d", enAU);
```

you could modify your method to include the language and culture as a parameter

```
public static string ConvertDateTimeToDate(string dateTimeString, String langCulture) {

    CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo(langCulture);
    DateTime dt = DateTime.MinValue;

    if (DateTime.TryParse(dateTimeString, out dt))
    {
        return dt.ToString("d",culture);
    }
    return dateTimeString;
  }
```

**Edit**
You may also want to look at the [overloaded tryParse method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9h21f14e.aspx) if you need to parse the string against a particular language/culture...

Comment: Thank you. The above code works. And yes, I'll be passing in language codes as parameters to produce localized date strings for various international languages.

Comment: A bit late for me to ask, but do you have the MSDN Reference?

Comment: @Steve I think it was just for example purposes. We aren't limited to the `d` format. And if sb wants to use another format I'll let the following article for reference: [Custom date and time format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings)

Answer (score 6):

Use an overload of `ToString()` instead of a `ToShortDateString()` method.  Supply an `IFormatProvider`.

This should be helpful in forming a specific date-time string:

http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/

This should be helpful with localization issues:

[How do you handle localization / CultureInfo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/920244/how-do-you-handle-localization-cultureinfo)

Comment: Thank you for the examples above. They will be very helpful at formatting the date strings for our different international languages.

Comment: I just tried to upvote, but it looks like I need 15 Reputation to Vote Up. Sorry, I'm still a noob at StackOverflow. :-|