# Convert.ToDateTime() Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, date, datetime

I have one string ,it's look like a date format is 01/04/2013

For `string date="01/04/2013"`

The above string format lik a : **01 is Date , 04 is Month , and 2013 year .**

Now i am using `convert.todatetime()`

See below :

```
DateTime **DateTimeValue** =Convert.ToDateTime(date);
```

The DateTimeValue return in my system  : `01-04-2013T00:00:00` **// Date 1st and month 2nd**

But   when converting the same DateTimeValue  is return on other system `:04-01-2013T00:00:00` **//Month 1st and date 2nd**

Why The `Convert.DateTime()` is return  different ,different date in different system ????

**Answer :**

Now I changed my DataBase Coloumn DataType  DateTime to Nvarchar . So I  Shouldn't want convert To DateTime  . and this is working in all system .

Thanks guy's

Comment: It could be that the regional settings are different on the two machines you're using.

Comment: Probably has to do with the culture settings - that'd be my first guess.

Comment: It looks like a culture setting/localization issue. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5798908/how-to-produce-localized-date-string-with-cultureinfo

Comment: Convert.ToDateTime depends on the CurrentCulture. Use explicit culture overload.

Comment: SO How can we solve this.

Comment: I don't want UK format . I want Indian date time  format !

Answer (score 4):

> Why The Convert.DateTime() is return different ,different date in
>   different system ????

Because it uses the current culture to convert the string to datetime. In some culture the month comes before the date and in others vice-versa.

You can specify the culture or use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`(which is similar to `en-US`)  or you can use [`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact.aspx) where you can specify the format.

```
string date="01/04/2013";
 // day 4 month 1
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(date, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

or

```
// day 4 month 1
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

In general it is a good idea to use the `TryParse` methods to detect if the input is in the correct format.

Answer (score 0):

It's a regional/localisation settings thing. The way to ensure this doesn't happen without knowing about these settings is to setup the date string like this: `yyyy-mm-dd`, e.g. `2013-04-01` which will always be seen as the 1st April 2013.

More info about `Convert.ToDateTime` here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhz1w05e.aspx

The pertinent bit:

> If value is not null, the return value is the result of invoking the DateTime.Parse method on value using the formatting information in a DateTimeFormatInfo object that is initialized for the current culture.

Answer (score 0):

If you go on the control panel on your PC, there will be an option for Region and Language (this may vary in name depending on your version of Windows). From you here you can specify the format of long and short dates and times.

If you want the format to be exactly the same, use the ToString() method on the datetime with a format set, described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

you can try this :

```
string date = "01/04/2013";
        DateTime dtTime;
        if (DateTime.TryParseExact(date, "dd/MM/yyyy",
           System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
           System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out dtTime))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(dtTime);
        }
```