# SqlCommand ExecuteNonquery strange exception

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime, sqlcommand, sqlparameter

I want to insert a record to SQL Server Database but I got a strange exception while ExecuteNonQuery() process. I got this exception:

```
ExecuteNonQuery requires an open and available Connection. 
The connection's current state is closed.
```

However my problem is not related with this. I am definitely sure that my connection's current state is Open. My problem is one of my parameters in my query. Here is my query:

```
                  sql = "update EMAIL_CONNECTIONS " +
                             "set END_DATE=@EndDate, " +
                             "STATUS=@Status, " +
                             "STATUS_DATE=@StatusDate, " +
                             "CATEGORY_CODE=@CategoryCode, " +
                             "EMAILOUT_SENTDATE=@EmailOutSentDate, " +
                             "TO_ADDRESS=@ToAddress " +
                             "where SESSIONID=@SessionId " +
                             "and STATUS = 'Inprocess'; ";
                sql += "insert into ICS_EMAIL_CONNECTIONS_TRX(SESSIONID, AGENTID, STATUS, FIELD1) " +
                       "values(@SessionId, @AgentId, @Status, 'Sended this mail')";
```

Exception throw because of the @EmailOutSentDate parameter. It does not accept Datetime format or something I dont know. When I give DateTime.Now to this parameter query runs successfully. I also tried DBNull.Value and query runs perfectly. DateTime problem is not related with the Exception.

```
   SqlConnection _cnn = new SqlConnection();
   _cnn.ConnectionString = connectionString;
   _cnn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, _cnn);                    
   cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@EndDate", DateTime.Now));
   cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Status", "Sent"));
   DateTime result = DateTime.MinValue;
   result = DateTime.ParseExact(result.ToString("yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss.fff"), "yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss.fff", null);
                DateTime newdate = DateTime.SpecifyKind(result, DateTimeKind.Local);
   cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@EmailOutSentDate", newdate));                   
   cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ToAddress", interaction.AllAttributes["To"]));
   cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@StatusDate", DateTime.Now));
   cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CategoryCode", long.Parse(CategoryCode)));
   cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@SessionId", interaction.Id));
   cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@AgentId", Agent.AgentId));
   cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
   cmd.Dispose();
```

As you can see I have also tried DateTime.Kind property but still same Exception thrown. Where is the problem? Any suggesstions?

Comment: does the stacktrace of the exception point back the the ExecuteNonQuery that is shown here? or is this exception perhaps coming from some exception handling that you aren't showing? Also: `using`. You should be `using(var _cnn = ...)` and `using(var cmd = ...)`

Comment: "It does not accept Datetime format or something" - datetimes are not sent to sql server as text; this is not a formatting issue

Comment: btw; unrelated - re the way you've built the `sql` value - did you know you can do that more simply using verbatim string literals? i.e. `sql = @"{your text here; can include line feeds etc just by pressing return}";`

Comment: You should use a `using` statement for mthe connection and the command. Otherwise the connection keeps open on error.

Comment: What are you doing here? You are converting `DateTime.MinValue` to `string`, then back to `DateTime` with `DateTime.ParseExact`, finally you are using `DateTime.SpecifyKind` on it. The result is the same: `DateTime.MinValue` which is not supported in sql-server(starts with January 1, 1753).

Answer (score 1):

What exactly are you trying to do? It looks like you are trying to insert a dummy date instead of having a null value in the db? If this is the case, you should stick with inserting a null value instead of a date that has no actual meaning.

If you actually have a DateTime value that you wan't to insert as localized value, this might help you: [How to produce localized date string with CultureInfo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5798908/how-to-produce-localized-date-string-with-cultureinfo)

Here is a update method we use in our old db layer when not working with EF and it will give you a safer code. Notice that you don't need to open the connection until you actually need to execute the query, and using a *using* statement will ensure that you dispose of your SqlCommand.
The _connection property is private and used for all methods in this class, and is set in the constructor by DependencyInjection.

```
_connection = new SqlConnection(this._connectionString);

public int Update(string query, Dictionary<string, string> commandParams)
    {
        int affectedRows = 0;
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, _connection))
        {
            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            foreach (var param in commandParams)
            {
                if (param.Value == null)
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue(param.Key, DBNull.Value);
                else
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue(param.Key, param.Value);
            }

            try
            {
                _connection.Open();
                affectedRows = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            finally
            {
                _connection.Close();
                command.Parameters.Clear();
            }
        }

        return affectedRows;
    }
```