# DevExpress DateTime format String - no AM/PM for Russian locale

Tags: c#, devexpress

I am using following time format pattern:

```
column.DisplayFormat.FormatType = DevExpress.Utils.FormatType.DateTime;
column.DisplayFormat.FormatString = "DD/mm/yyyy hh:mm tt";
```

It works exactly as expected for US locale. But after changing to Russian locale AP/PM signs disappeared. `"<"` and `">"` appears instead. How to solve it?

Comment: Yeah, `ru-RU` culture (guessing it's not the Tatar one) does have `AMDesignator` and `PMDesignator` properties as an empty string. You can `Clone` this russian culture and set these properties what ever you want and use _this_ culture as a `Current(UI)Culture` which I'm not 100% sure this will happen for entire application http://stackoverflow.com/questions/468791/is-there-a-way-of-setting-culture-for-a-whole-application-all-current-threads-a

Comment: You might look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5798908/how-to-produce-localized-date-string-with-cultureinfo) for some info on date localization.

Comment: By the way, there is no `DD` as a custom date and time specifiers. You need to use `dd` instead. Custom specifiers are case sensitive. Also `mm` specifier is for minutes, but `MM` specifier is for months.

Answer (score 0):

Most people outside of USA use a 24 hour clock; 13:00 instead of 1 PM.  It's also problematic to determine if the date is dd/mm or mm/dd; so it good practice to use dd MMM yyyy; e.g. 2 Jan 2015.

So you should use

```
column.DisplayFormat.FormatString = "dd MMM yyyy HH:mm";
```