# Convert string to dateTime US

Tags: c#

I have a string in the following format.

`Ene  1 2017 12:00AM`

I need to convert it to a date:

`Jan  1 2017 12:00AM`    OR    `01/01/2017`

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Please take a look at this guide for writing a good question: https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use `DateTime.ParseExact()` with a cultureinfo relevant to the source language that string is in. Then you'll need to call `.ToString()` on the DateTime that parse gave you, with the en-us culture

[How to produce localized date string with CultureInfo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5798908/how-to-produce-localized-date-string-with-cultureinfo) has some examples