# Convert Arabic AM/PM to english AM/PM in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, date, datetime

I have below code to convert date time from text to 12 hours date format, But showing Arabic AM & PM .

How to get the result in English AM/PM format

Code:

```
string iDate = "02/06/2018 16:58:42";         
DateTime CHECKTIME = Convert.ToDateTime(iDate);
Label1.Text=CHECKTIME.ToString();
```

Result:

```
02/06/2018 04:58:42 م
```

Expected Result:

```
02/06/2018 04:58:42 PM
```

Comment: [Formatting Date and Time for a Specific Culture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5hh873ya(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: Here u goo https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5798908/how-to-produce-localized-date-string-with-cultureinfo

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your [`CurrentCulture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture) is based on some arabic culture and that's why you get `م` character as a [`PMDesignator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.pmdesignator) as an output.

You can always specify your format and culture as a parameters in your `ToString` method by the way to get the result you want.

```
Label1.Text = CHECKTIME.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
// I assume 02 is day and 06 is month
```

Comment: 04:58:42 06/02/2018 PM  => i am getting like this with "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt" formating

Comment: @SamBinHam Are you _really_ sure? The code couldn't generate that output. Maybe it can be a [right to left](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-to-left) issue?

Comment: Its fine now, When i change the language and App pools's identity to Local server

Comment: @SamBinHam Good to hear.